# Error on Apollo GraphQL: Expecting a parsed GraphQL document

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, jestjs, enzyme

I am getting an error when on my test regarding to Apollo GraphQL:

> Expecting a parsed GraphQL document. Perhaps you need to wrap the query string in a "gql" tag?

This is the test I have so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from 'react-redux';
import { MockedProvider as ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo/test-utils';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { CouriersSelect } from '../../CouriersSelect';
import GetAllCouriers from '../../containers/GetAllCouriers';

import store from '../../../../redux/store';

import mocks from '../__fixtures__/couriers-mock';

jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
  // this mock makes sure any components using the translate HoC receive the t function as a prop
  translate: () => Component => {
    Component.defaultProps = { ...Component.defaultProps, t: key => key }; // eslint-disable-line
    return Component;
  },
}));

describe('CouriersSelect test', () => {
  let props;

  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      t: k => k,
      handleCouriers: jest.fn(),
    };
  });

  it('correctly renders CouriersSelect component', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <ApolloProvider mocks={mocks}>
        <ReduxProvider store={store}>
          <GetAllCouriers>
            <CouriersSelect {...props} />
          </GetAllCouriers>
        </ReduxProvider>
      </ApolloProvider>,
    );

    console.log(wrapper.debug());

    expect(wrapper.find('SelectSkeleton')).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

And this is the component I am testing:

```
import { Select, SelectItem } from 'carbon-components-react';
import React from 'react';
import { translate } from 'react-i18next';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import GetAllCouriers from './containers/GetAllCouriers';

export const CouriersSelect = ({ t, handleCouriers }) => (
  <GetAllCouriers>
    {({ data }) => (
      <Select
        id="select-2"
        onChange={handleCouriers}
      >
        {data.map(carriers => (
          <SelectItem
            key={carriers.name}
            value={carriers.name}
            text={carriers.name}
          />
        ))}
      </Select>
    )}
  </GetAllCouriers>
);

CouriersSelect.propTypes = {
  t: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  handleCouriers: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default translate()(CouriersSelect);
```

So what could I be missing?

EDIT:

Apollo code:

Query:

```
export const GET_ALL_COURIERS = gql`
  query GetAllCouriers {
    GetAllCouriers {
      id
      url
      keyName
      name
    }
  }
`;
```

Call:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { translate } from 'react-i18next';
import { SelectSkeleton } from 'carbon-components-react';
import { GET_ALL_COURIERS } from './GraphQLQuery';
import ErrorState from '../../../global/components/ErrorState';

const GetAllCouriers = ({ t, children, softlayerAccountId }) => (
  <Query
    query={GET_ALL_COURIERS}
    context={{ uri: `/graphql?ims_account=${softlayerAccountId}` }}
  >
    {({ loading, error, data, refetch }) => {
      let getAllCouriers;

      if (error) {
        return (
          <div className="empty-state-table">
            <ErrorState description={t('shipments.errorMessage')} />
          </div>
        );
      }

      if (loading) return <SelectSkeleton />;

      if (data && data.GetAllCouriers) {
        getAllCouriers = data.GetAllCouriers;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
      }

      return children({
        data: getAllCouriers,
        error,
        loading,
        refetch,
        softlayerAccountId,
      });
    }}
  </Query>
);

GetAllCouriers.propTypes = {
  t: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  softlayerAccountId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default compose(
  connect(store => ({
    softlayerAccountId: store.global.softlayerAccountId,
  })),
  translate(),
)(GetAllCouriers);
```

Comment: This error is being thrown by apollo and there's nothing specific to apollo in the code you posted. We'd need to see the code for `GetAllCouriers`. As a side note, it looks like `GetAllCouriers` uses the render prop pattern but you're not passing it a function in your test.

Comment: @DanielRearden see my code above. I did an edit

Comment: Hey there. Could you post the code of the actual mock definition? In my case, where I had the same error message while wrapping the query in a gql tag, I was not correctly writing the request portion of the mock.